# Why EF core executes n query for n+1 query

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to get Departments with last DepartmentLog, but ef core executes n+1 query. And works so slow. I have 10 000 rows on Department table and 12 000 rows on DepartmentLogs. I am not sure it must work 1.5s - 2s for executing like this query.

```
 var query2 = _unitOfWork.Departments.GetDbSet()
            .Include(p => p.CreatedUser)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Employee)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Department = p,
                DepartmentLog = _unitOfWork.DepartmentLogs.GetDbSet()
                .Include(m => m.CreatedUser)
                .ThenInclude(m => m.Employee)
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedAt)
                .FirstOrDefault(m => m.DepartmentId == p.Id)
            })
        .Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: Because you are calling `_unitOfWork.DepartmentLogs.GetDbSet()...` inside the query, EF cannot translate this into SQL so must do it all in memory.

Comment: I tried 'p.DepartmentLogs.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedAt).FirstOrDefault()' but its works same

Comment: but without '.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DepartmentId == p.Id)' if i get all its execute in 1 query

Answer (score 0):

The lambda you're passing to `Select` is executed for each item in the result set. Since you're making a query in that lambda, you're going to have N queries issued, one for each item in the result set.

The reason it only generates one extra query when you remove `FirstOrDefault`, is that you're returning the all the department logs, which then allows EF to add them to the object cache, where it can pull them out from later, instead of issuing a new query. With `FirstOrDefault`, you're only returning one, so EF caches *that*, but on the next run of the lambda, you're selecting a different one that it doesn't have cached.

To use `FirstOrDefault` and still have just one extra query, you should run this query *first*:

```
var departmentLogs = await _unitOfWork.DepartmentLogs.GetDbSet()
    .Include(m => m.CreatedUser)
    .ThenInclude(m => m.Employee)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedAt)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Then, in your `Select`:

```
.Select(p => new
{
    Department = p,
    DepartmentLog = departmentLogs.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DepartmentId == p.Id)
})
```

Then, it will run the `FirstOrDefault` on the result set already in memory. However, this requires returning *all* the logs, which could be more problematic performance-wise, if there's a ton of them. You'll have to profile each way and see which ends up being better in your particular circumstance.

Alternatively, a probably preferably, you can simply create this query as a stored procedure, and then just call the stored procedure to get your results, instead of using LINQ to build a query. There's only so much EF can do to optimize the query, and this is a highly inefficient query, no matter what you do.

Comment: Thanks for reply, In logs may have millions of records, i dont wanna to load all. After Select  I have projectTo Dto with Automapper and sorting and pagination option,  I think it must be done on query level?

Comment: A stored procedure is your best bet then. You can build the sorting and paging into that, so you just pass in the page number, field to sort by, etc. as params.

Comment: The stored procedure can return your DTO, so no need to project either.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if EF 6 handles this the same way EF Core does? If so, the answer is yes. This isn't specific to EF; it's a function of the LINQ.